# Multi tenancy with varying deployment schedules

Tags: java, spring, jboss

Currently using JBoss 5.2 + Java 8 (Upgrading JBoss is soon to come). We have the opportunity to revitalize the application with a strong core for multi-tenancy support, so assume this can be started from scratch.

Our Java+Spring application is a simple web app:

- Exposes various REST services to be utilized by our client implementations (mobile native + browser).
- Connects various systems to complete a 'tenant' implementation.

We build out our tenant implementation utilizing our standardized client/server patterns with customization on each side. On the service side, this involves connecting to various external services including the specific tenant's back-end system for querying or end-product submission.

It's a domain driven design, treating the various services as pluggable utilities based on an interface. The services basically act as a translation and request/response handler to and from our standardized domain objects. Currently the various service interfaces, common services, and tenant-specific modules are broken off into separate projects and maven'd together via POM in JAR format. Also note we currently have a single controller layer since the client/server interfaces are standardized for our solution.

**My question** is: How can we support releases of various tenants without bringing down the JVM?

The current thought was to be able to dynamically swap the tenant JAR dependencies. Right now the tenant-specific services are designated by spring bean injection - tenant config determined by the URL requests are made with (secured by a session token).

Consider the following scenario of 3 tenants:

- Tenant A releases monthly @ 3am on a Saturday
- Tenant B wants agile/security releases every 2 weeks @ 9am Saturday
- Tenant C wants planned development releases every quarter @ 8pm on a Wednesday

Definitely need to ensure security of the application, so don't want to break the class loading to do anything shady.

Any help/direction would be appreciated and will update with what we end up with.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I've come up with so far is a single JVM hosting multiple WARs.
Components separated into their own projects:

- 'core' - Controllers, web service factories, etc..
- Service interfaces
- Domain Objects
- Tenant Implementations (each their own)

This split of projects allows them to be built individually and take advantage of Maven's versioning system (snapshots).

Each implementation(tenant) now has an 'app' project that mavens the various components and services together. This is a different project than the Tenant Implementations - allows that one to be reused by other projects that would utilize the same domain objects. These 'app' projects would provide all configurations for the app and sub components, being built into their own WAR.

Deployment process is as said - a single JVM that doesn't get cycled while starting/stopping WARs. We currently run an older version of JBoss, so messing with the class loader has been the main issue, but not bad. Looking to upgrade or separate WARs into their own server areas under JBoss.

Going to look into a custom class loader via database storage for JARs or into moving to a Docker setup.